# Rolling Correlation Calculation with Pandas or NumPy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find an efficient way for the following problem:

Two data frames, each with the following data:
1st one: `id, date, value`

Sample Data:

```
id, date, value
f130,200701,0.016196
f130,200702,-0.027798
f130,200703,-0.014868
f130,200704,0.017801
f130,200705,-0.032700
f130,200706,0.049529
f130,200707,0.011610
f130,200708,-0.008145
f130,200709,-0.001493
f130,200710,0.009719
f130,200711,-0.007775
f130,200712,-0.007835
f131,200701,0.044754
f131,200702,0.004679
f131,200703,-0.011824
f131,200704,0.007252
f131,200705,0.029877
f131,200706,0.001748
f131,200707,0.001047
f131,200708,-0.003137
f131,200709,0.001748
f131,200710,0.006632
f131,200711,-0.012136
f131,200712,0.004914
```

2nd one: `id_2, date, value`

Sample Data:

```
id_2, date, value
d_1,200701,0.026316
d_1,200702,-0.004487
d_1,200703,-0.027044
d_1,200704,-0.035076
d_1,200705,0.010288
d_1,200706,-0.031908
d_1,200707,-0.001403
d_1,200708,0.009831
d_1,200709,0.040334
d_1,200710,0.018048
d_1,200711,0.011819
d_1,200712,0.000000
d_2,200701,0.000000
d_2,200702,0.028553
d_2,200703,-0.037224
d_2,200704,0.041284
d_2,200705,0.151038
d_2,200706,0.061236
d_2,200707,0.001030
d_2,200708,-0.042203
d_2,200709,0.000000
d_2,200710,0.006986
d_2,200711,-0.018676
d_2,200712,0.001087
```

What i need, is a rolling window correlation (rolling over `date` column) between the two `value` columns for all `id & id_2` pairs
Essentially, my output should be: `"id vs id_2", date, corr`
So, for `d1 vs f130`, for `200706`, i calculate the correlation between values from `d1` and `f130` starting from `200706` going back `6` months. The same for all pairs.
Expected output:

```
id_pair, date, value
d1_f130,200706,-0.375238392
d1_f130,200707,-0.667154011
d1_f130,200708,-0.636064899
d1_f130,200709,-0.672029012
d1_f130,200710,-0.653719992
d1_f130,200711,-0.802893705
d1_f130,200712,-0.03120143
d1_f131,200706,0.870717009
d1_f131,200707,0.61076152
d1_f131,200708,0.400632396
d1_f131,200709,0.05064842
d1_f131,200710,0.087102168
d1_f131,200711,-0.012306865
d1_f131,200712,0.05170204
d2_f130,200706,-0.170979922
d2_f130,200707,-0.15363222
d2_f130,200708,-0.089709021
d2_f130,200709,-0.227564277
d2_f130,200710,-0.252391258
d2_f130,200711,0.94878745
d2_f130,200712,0.619029635
d2_f131,200706,0.358385975
d2_f131,200707,0.952074283
d2_f131,200708,0.930805345
d2_f131,200709,0.919101445
d2_f131,200710,0.904473885
d2_f131,200711,0.47080201
d2_f131,200712,0.640334152
```

Using for loops to iterate over ids and dates takes days... (number of id's ~15000, id_2 ~ 300, dates ~ 300)

Any ideas?

Comment: can you please give a sample of your datasets ? With  the expected output?

Comment: Thank you for the example, see Update in my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48166049/3941704) to fit your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have two dataframes as follow:

```
# I change the columns name to simplify your pb
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id1':id1, 'date':d1,'value1':v1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id2':id2, 'date':d1,'value2':v2})
```

You can then merge both to have a single `df` like:

```
df = df1.merge(df2,how='outer',on='date')

print(df) #for ex:
                   date    id1   value1    id2  value2
0    2008-01-01 13:30:00    0  59.727276    5  49.423527
1    2008-01-01 13:30:00    0  59.727276    4  49.659602
```

Now groupby ids and apply your rolling correlation:

```
dfs = [] #create a collection to store each groupby result
for n, g in df.groupby(['id1','id2']):
    _df = pd.DataFrame({'ids':[n]*len(g.date),'date':g.date})
    #compute the correlations between the series of values
    _df['corr'] = g.value1.rolling(10).corr(g.value2)
    dfs.append(_df)

#concatenate your dataframes to have a single one 
final_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)


print(final_df) #show result. for ex:
#Note that first 9 rows for each ids pair are NaN according to my rolling corr options.
                   date     ids       corr
0    2008-01-01 13:34:00  (0, 0)       NaN
1    2008-01-01 13:34:00  (0, 0)       NaN
2    2008-01-01 13:35:00  (0, 0)       NaN
3    2008-01-01 13:37:00  (0, 0)       NaN
4    2008-01-01 13:37:00  (0, 0)       NaN
5    2008-01-01 13:37:00  (0, 0)       NaN
6    2008-01-01 13:38:00  (0, 0)       NaN
7    2008-01-01 13:38:00  (0, 0)       NaN
8    2008-01-01 13:40:00  (0, 0)       NaN
9    2008-01-01 13:41:00  (0, 0)  0.423877
10   2008-01-01 13:42:00  (0, 0)  0.555128
```

Note:

- In my example `ids` are `(int,int)`
- See documentation for [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), [rolling](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) and [correlation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.window.Rolling.corr.html)

---

**Update**:
You can rename the headers of your example to fit this answer like this:

```
df1.columns  = ['id1','date','value1']
df2.columns  = ['id2','date','value2']
```

You can change `ids` to fit your expected output replacing
`'ids':[n]*len(g.date)`
by
`'ids':['_'.join(n)]*len(g.date)`
for instance.

Comment: Thanks! Working as expected!